# How do I exclude a folder in an ant jar task?

Tags: ant, jar

I am trying to build a java project using ant. I have to exclude a particular directory from base directory for jar packaging. Here is the code snippet.

```
<target name="jar" depends="wsdl2java,oss.init,oss.request.compile">
    <copy todir="${build.lib.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${oss.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.*" excludes="**/weblogic.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.conf.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${oss.conf.dir}" includes="**/*.*"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${oss.build.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${oss.run.dir}" includes="**/*.*"/>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${oss.build.dir}/osstool2.5.5.jar" basedir="${oss.class.dir}" excludes="**/dms/*">

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Created-By" value="${owner}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". lib/antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar.jar lib/log4j.jar
                lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
                lib/spring.jar lib/axis.jar lib/axis-ant.jar lib/jaxrpc-api.jar 
                lib/webserviceclient.jar lib/webserviceclient+ssl.jar 
                lib/wlclient.jar lib/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar lib/wsse.jar lib/ala-castor.jar lib/log4j.jar lib/log4j.jar lib/xercesImpl.jar 
                lib/ala-nbi-commons-1.3.0.jar lib/ala-nbi-notification-plugins.jar lib/ala-nbi-webservice-client-1.3.0.jar 
                lib/axis.jar lib/axis-ant.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar lib/jaxrpc-api.jar lib/webserviceclient.jar lib/webserviceclient+ssl.jar 
                lib/wlclient.jar lib/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar lib/wsse.jar lib/commons-logging.jar">
            </attribute>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the project build? Do you get an error? What is the error? More information is needed.

Comment: yes build work but from jar the excluded folder is not removed.

Comment: If the folder exist, but there is no file in it. You can set `excludes` to `**/dms/**`.